# issue with using Requestmappinghandlermapping in beans.xml spring 4.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am upgrading my proj to spring 4.x from Spring 3.0. Accordingly, I have updated my beans.xml with new classes from the old classes(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping & AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter). I assume, I am facing issues with the way I am handling RequestMappingHandlerMapping in spring 4.x

```
<code> 

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"
    p:interceptors-ref="threadSessionDataInterceptor" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="stringMarshallingConverter"/>                               
            <ref bean="jsonMarshallingConverter"/>    
            <ref bean="xmlMarshallingConverter"/>
            <ref bean="xmlMarshallingConverter2"/>    
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
 </code>
```

When I am starting the server after upgrading to spring 4.x, I am getting the following INFO messages in the stacktrace where it is throwing exception.

11:19:30,879 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) Mapped "{[/sample/validateexample.json]}" onto public void com.fnservice.web.VerificatonController.addNotes(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception

11:19:30,915 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) Mapped "{[/init/doInitialConfig.json],methods=[GET]}" onto public void com.fnservice.web.InitialConfController.doInitialConfig(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception

Below, I am mentioning the java code of VerificationController class for which server is throwing java.lang.Exception.

```
<code>

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sample/*")
public class AdVerificationController {

private final static Log log =   LogFactory.getLog(AdVerificationController.class);

@Autowired
AdVerificationService adVerificationService;


@RequestMapping(value = "validateexample.json")
public void addNotes(@RequestParam(value = "validateLane1", required = false)String Line1,
        @RequestParam(value = "validateLane2", required = false)String Line2,
        @RequestParam(value = "validateTe", required = false)String Te, 
        Model model)throws Exception {
         {
    AddXML add = new AddXML();
    VerificationXML VerificationResponse = new AddVerificationXML();

   ......... rest of code
```

But, when I run the same code with Spring 3.0, it is not throwing any exception. Please advice me as to whether I am doing anything wrong here.
Below I am pasting the stacktrace when I run with Spring 3.0.

18:17:09,113 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Mapped URL path [/address/validateExample.json] onto handler 'VerificationController'

18:17:09,129 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Mapped URL path [/init/doInitialConfig.json] onto handler 'initialConfController'